# Predicate Criteria Not Working When Adding From List<int>

Tags: c#, wpf, list, datagrid, predicate

I have list of `int` that correspond to many Contract's IDs. The idea is that the user can add a 'favorite' `Contract` whose ID is then stored in a Database. I retrieve the List for that person then filter down a `DataGrid` so only the favorite `Contract` shows.

If I add a hardcoded `ID` to the List of `Predicates` there is no issue, like so;

```
criteria.Clear();
if (favouritesCheckBox.IsChecked == true)
{
    criteria.Add(new Predicate<ContractModel>(x => x.ID == 6966));
}
```

However, when I try to add from the `List<int>` that contains the `IDs`. I do this like so;

```
if (favouritesCheckBox.IsChecked == true)
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= 48; i++)
    {
        if (favouriteContractList[i] != 0)
        {
            criteria.Add(new Predicate<ContractModel>(x => x.ID == favouriteContractList[i]));
        }
    }
}
```

There are a few things from the get go that confuse me. Firstly, `favouriteContractList.Count` results in `50`, however I can't do `for (int i = 0; i <= 50; i++)`. Secondly, I've printed out `favouriteContractList[i].ToString()` throughout the loop and there seems to be no issue with the `IDs` being stored. However when I check my `ComboBox` to filter the `DataGrid` I am left with just an empty grid when I try to do it this way.

Comment: is it on .NET 3.5?

Comment: not answers your question but will simplify and avoid some issues n the first place, use foreach(int num in favouriteContractList.Where(n => n != 0) ) { criteria.Add(new Predicate<ContractModel>(x => x.ID == num); }

Comment: @sll thanks for your help, I'll add it in to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the favouriteContractList[i] into a variable, like so:

```
if (favouritesCheckBox.IsChecked == true)
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= 48; i++)
    {
        int id = favouriteContractList[i];
        if (id != 0)
        {
            criteria.Add(new Predicate<ContractModel>(x => x.ID == id));
        }
}
```

Something to do with the way it delays building it causes it to not resolve like you'd think it would. It probably thinks 'i' is 49 when it gets around to actually using it. This would explain why you can't let 'i' get above 49 -- it would be out of range of your 50 ints in the list.

I just noticed you said you have 50 items and can't do 'i <= 50', since indexing starts at 0, i=50 is the 51st item (which doesn't exist).

Comment: Hmm still no luck unfortunately, thanks for your answer. I can still hardcode the ID in as I demonstrated in my question and it works perfectly, it just doesn't seem to want to add the ID from the list...